# Llamar a un procedure que devuelve una tabla

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

necesito llamar a un procedure que me devuelve una tabla con unos resultados.
Lo hago a través de un servicio en C# que tengo en mi proyecto de Net core os dejo el código aquí:

```
using (var transaction = new CommittableTransaction(new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
        {
            using (SqlConnection sourceConnection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
            {
                sourceConnection.Open();
                try
                {
                    string query = "EXECUTE dbo.Procedure1'";
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, sourceConnection);
                    
                    SqlParameter param1= cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Gid1", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
                    param1.Value = Id1;
                    SqlParameter param2 = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Fecha", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                    param2.Value = fecha;
                    SqlParameter param3 = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
                    param3.Value = Id2;
                    SqlParameter param4 = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Id3", SqlDbType.Int);
                    param4.Value = Id3;

                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            Result m = new Result();
                        }
                        rdr.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    sourceConnection.Close();
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
                finally
                {
                    sourceConnection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

El problema que tengo es que no entra en el READER y no se porque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno después de hacer varias pruebas y buscar mas rato por internet al final soluciones el problema que es una chorrada el problema esta en estas dos líneas del código

```
string query = "EXECUTE dbo.Procedure1'";
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, sourceConnection);
```

Lo he solucionando de esta manera

```
//string query = "EXECUTE dbo.Procedure1'";
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Procedure1", sourceConnection);
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Creo que lo estaba llamando mal por eso no me ejecutaba el reader.